# Falling snow...but only while mouse is moving?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a client who is (for reasons of her own...!) desperate to have 1990s-style falling sparkles coming from the top of her webpage. There seem to exist a ton of snowfall scripts to facilitate this, but the problem is she only wants the animation to persist while the mouse is moving - when the mouse stops, she wants the sparkles to stop falling.

Peter Gehrig's Snowmaker gives the closest visual effect to what I'm looking for, but I just can't figure out how to stop it animating when the mouse stops moving. My Javascript is really terrible (I'm working on it with the help of Codecademy, but it's taking time) and I generally get by by patching together bits and pieces of existing code, but I can't figure this one out.

Gehrig's code is as follows, and I'm not sure if it's possible to make it only fire while the mouse is moving...

```
    <script>
    // Set the number of snowflakes (more than 30 - 40 not recommended)
    var snowmax=35

    // Set the colors for the snow. Add as many colors as you like
    var snowcolor=new Array("#aaaacc","#ddddFF","#ccccDD")

    // Set the fonts, that create the snowflakes. Add as many fonts as you like
    var snowtype=new Array("Arial Black","Arial Narrow","Times","Comic Sans MS")

    // Set the letter that creates your snowflake 
    var snowletter="+"

    // Set the speed of sinking (recommended values range from 0.3 to 2)
    var sinkspeed=0.6

    // Set the maximal-size of your snowflaxes
   var snowmaxsize=22

   // Set the minimal-size of your snowflaxes
   var snowminsize=8

   // Set the snowing-zone
   // Set 1 for all-over-snowing, set 2 for left-side-snowing 
   // Set 3 for center-snowing, set 4 for right-side-snowing
   var snowingzone=1


   var snow=new Array()
   var marginbottom
   var marginright
   var timer
   var i_snow=0
   var x_mv=new Array();
   var crds=new Array();
   var lftrght=new Array();
   var browserinfos=navigator.userAgent 
   var ie5=document.all&&document.getElementById&&!browserinfos.match(/Opera/)
   var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all
   var opera=browserinfos.match(/Opera/)  
   var browserok=ie5||ns6||opera

   function randommaker(range) {        
        rand=Math.floor(range*Math.random())
   return rand
   }

   function initsnow() {
if (ie5 || opera) {
    marginbottom = document.body.clientHeight
    marginright = document.body.clientWidth
}
else if (ns6) {
    marginbottom = window.innerHeight
    marginright = window.innerWidth
}
var snowsizerange=snowmaxsize-snowminsize
for (i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
    crds[i] = 0;                      
    lftrght[i] = Math.random()*15;         
    x_mv[i] = 0.03 + Math.random()/10;
    snow[i]=document.getElementById("s"+i)
    snow[i].style.fontFamily=snowtype[randommaker(snowtype.length)]
    snow[i].size=randommaker(snowsizerange)+snowminsize
    snow[i].style.fontSize=snow[i].size
    snow[i].style.color=snowcolor[randommaker(snowcolor.length)]
    snow[i].sink=sinkspeed*snow[i].size/5
    if (snowingzone==1) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright-snow[i].size)}
    if (snowingzone==2) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)}
    if (snowingzone==3) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-

snow[i].size)+marginright/4}
        if (snowingzone==4) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/2}
        snow[i].posy=randommaker(6*marginbottom-marginbottom-6*snow[i].size)
        snow[i].style.left=snow[i].posx
        snow[i].style.top=snow[i].posy
    }
    movesnow()
}

function movesnow() {
    for (i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
        crds[i] += x_mv[i];
        snow[i].posy+=snow[i].sink
        snow[i].style.left=snow[i].posx+lftrght[i]*Math.sin(crds[i]);
        snow[i].style.top=snow[i].posy

        if (snow[i].posy>=marginbottom-6*snow[i].size || parseInt(snow[i].style.left)>(marginright-3*lftrght[i])){
            if (snowingzone==1) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright-snow[i].size)}
            if (snowingzone==2) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)}
            if (snowingzone==3) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/4}
            if (snowingzone==4) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/2}
            snow[i].posy=0
        }
    }
    var timer=setTimeout("movesnow()",50)
}

for (i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
    document.write("<span id='s"+i+"' style='position:absolute;top:-"+snowmaxsize+"'>"+snowletter+"</span>")
    }
    if (browserok) {
 window.onload=initsnow
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: On mouse move, start it moving, then on mouse stop, after a 50ms delay, if it didn't start moving again, stop it. First, of course, you have to figure out how to stop and start it on demand.

Comment: That is a horrible piece of code. I suggest you find something else or write your own.

Comment: My JS isn't good enough even to know what's horrible about it. Unfortunately I'm totally unable to write my own at this point. I might have to give up on this one.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the right solution for you, but clojurescript core.async lets you loop over functions while an event is happening. There's an article [here](http://swannodette.github.io/2013/07/31/extracting-processes/) on CSP, which would take care of this if you have a function to make sparkles.

Comment: Just looking at basic stuff, like how it uses document.write to insert HTML strings instead of creating proper elements, and the way setInterval is called with a function that is being eval'ed, it's clear that whoever wrote that code had no idea what they where doing, and it thouroughly sucks, to be kind.

Comment: @adeneo I really hope one day soon I can look back at this and realise how much it sucks (I had no idea inserting HTML strings was bad practice, for instance). I keep being asked to do more and more JS work and I just don't have the skills for it at the moment. I'm a designer not a developer!

Comment: It's not really the HTML strings, but more `document.write` that is the bad practice, but creating the elements with javascripts `createElement` or similar methods is the preferred way of doing it, and it will create valid working elements. `document.write` shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if this works. Keep in mind there is a limit on the number of flakes so it won't always generate new flakes unless enough have landed already.

```
<script>
  var snowmax=35             // Set the number of snowflakes (more than 30 - 40 not recommended)
  var snowcolor=new Array("#aaaacc","#ddddFF","#ccccDD")      // Set the colors for the snow. Add as many colors as you like

  // Set the fonts, that create the snowflakes. Add as many fonts as you like
  var snowtype=new Array("Arial Black","Arial Narrow","Times","Comic Sans MS")

  var snowletter="+"      // Set the letter that creates your snowflake 
  var sinkspeed=0.6       // Set the speed of sinking (recommended values range from 0.3 to 2)
  var snowmaxsize=22      // Set the maximal-size of your snowflaxes
  var snowminsize=8       // Set the minimal-size of your snowflaxes

  // Set the snowing-zone
  // Set 1 for all-over-snowing, set 2 for left-side-snowing 
  // Set 3 for center-snowing, set 4 for right-side-snowing
  var snowingzone=1

  var snow=new Array()
  var marginbottom
  var marginright
  var timer
  var i_snow=0
  var x_mv=new Array();
  var crds=new Array();
  var lftrght=new Array();
  var browserinfos=navigator.userAgent 
  var ie5=document.all&&document.getElementById&&!browserinfos.match(/Opera/)
  var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all
  var opera=browserinfos.match(/Opera/)  
  var browserok=ie5||ns6||opera
  var mousemoving = false;

  function randommaker(range) {
    rand=Math.floor(range*Math.random())
    return rand
  }

  function initsnow() {
    if (ie5 || opera) {
      marginbottom = document.body.clientHeight
      marginright = document.body.clientWidth
    } else if (ns6) {
      marginbottom = window.innerHeight
      marginright = window.innerWidth
    }

    makeSnow();
    movesnow();
  }

function makeSnow() {
  var snowsizerange=snowmaxsize-snowminsize
  for (i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
    crds[i] = 0;
    lftrght[i] = Math.random()*15;
    x_mv[i] = 0.03 + Math.random()/10;
    snow[i] = document.getElementById("s"+i)
    snow[i].style.fontFamily=snowtype[randommaker(snowtype.length)]
    snow[i].size=randommaker(snowsizerange)+snowminsize
    snow[i].style.fontSize=snow[i].size
    snow[i].style.color=snowcolor[randommaker(snowcolor.length)]
    snow[i].sink=sinkspeed*snow[i].size/5
    if (snowingzone==1) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright-snow[i].size)}
    if (snowingzone==2) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)}
    if (snowingzone==3) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/4}
    if (snowingzone==4) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/2}
    snow[i].posy=randommaker(6*marginbottom-marginbottom-6*snow[i].size)
    snow[i].style.left=snow[i].posx
    snow[i].style.top=snow[i].posy
  }
}

function movesnow() {
  for (i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
    if (snow[i].posy<marginbottom-6*snow[i].size || parseInt(snow[i].style.left)<(marginright-3*lftrght[i])){
      crds[i] += x_mv[i];
      snow[i].posy+=snow[i].sink
      snow[i].style.left=snow[i].posx+lftrght[i]*Math.sin(crds[i]);
      snow[i].style.top=snow[i].posy
    }

    if (mousemoving) {
      if (snow[i].posy>=marginbottom-6*snow[i].size || parseInt(snow[i].style.left)>(marginright-3*lftrght[i])){
      if (snowingzone==1) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright-snow[i].size)}
      if (snowingzone==2) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)}
      if (snowingzone==3) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/4}
      if (snowingzone==4) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/2}
      snow[i].posy=0
      }
    }
  }
  var timer=setTimeout("movesnow()",50)
}

for (i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
  document.write("<span id='s"+i+"' style='position:absolute;top:-"+snowmaxsize+"'>"+snowletter+"</span>")
}

if (browserok) {
  window.onload=initsnow

  window.onmousemove = function() {
    mousemoving = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
      mousemoving = false;
    }, 500);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If it seems a little faster than before, adjust the sinkspeed variable to slow it down.

Comment: this also freezes the snow that's already been generated, though, rather than letting it fall but not generating any more. Is that the intended outcome?

Comment: oh, I misunderstood what you were trying to do then. I thought you wanted the snow to actually stop falling (freeze).

Comment: answers been updated, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This works great - now to sit down and try and figure out *why* it works. ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:  listen for a `mousemove` event, and set a timeout for 500ms to stop the snow.  When the mouse moves again, clear the timeout from last time, and set a new one.  JS Code:

```
var interval;
window.onmousemove=function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    startSnow();
    interval=setTimeout(stopSnow,500);
}
```

Where `startSnow()` and `stopSnow()` are functions provided by you.

**Edit: here's some code for the** `startSnow()` **and** `stopSnow()` **functions:**

```
var snowGoing=true;
function startSnow(){
    if(snowGoing===false){
        snowGoing=true;
        movesnow();
    }
}
function stopSnow(){
    if(snowGoing===true){
        snowGoing=false;
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
}
```

Comment: @EmmaW might want to ensure that startSnow cancels early if it is already started

Comment: This is definitely a good idea, but I'd put the timeout at something like 15ms. It needs to be near-instant when the mouse stops moving, and that's plenty of time to initiate another `mousemove` event.

Comment: OK I'm now realising I have absolutely no idea how to write the function itself - my JS is simply not good enough. Guessing I may have to outsource this one. :(

Comment: Where would this go, for instance, in the code above (even though it's apparently horrible)?

Comment: @EmmaW: I wrote a try at the start and stop function.  Let me know if it works.  And it could all go at the bottom of the code.

Comment: The problem is I have no idea how to actually make it snow. I understand that the code above will detect whether the animation is happening and make the opposite thing happen, but I don't know how to animate it. I also don't even know what order these should go in the code. I think this is just too advanced for me.

Comment: @SuperScript pasting this at the bottom of the code makes the speed of the snowflakes increase on mousemove but doesn't affect stopping or starting. Do I need to be referring to startSnow and stopSnow elsewhere in the code?